# Rails Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Total newbie to Rails and programming in general, so please forgive me if the answer to my question seems glaringly obvious. I've been doing a lot of reading including [the ROR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) but can't seem to find a scenario specific to the following situation:

I have three models scaffolded under one `User` model, and am trying to link them like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :malls, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :stores, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :cakes, :as => :cake_poly, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :mall
   has_many :cakes, :as => :cake_poly, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Cakes < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :cake_poly, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Will this work? If it does, is there a better way to implement this? If not, how else can I implement the associations?

The idea is that each `User` may have many `malls`, each `Mall` may have many `stores`, and both `malls` and `stores` may have many `cakes`.

Comment: *"Will this work?"* - You should try it yourself.

Comment: I have tried it, perhaps my question should have been: "is this the BEST way to implement the association?"

Comment: As you have posted it this code should not work: `:cake_poly` in `Cake` don't match `:cake_polymorphic` in `Store` and `Mall`. You should check the code and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out toro2k, edited the code and added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A key question for your design is the intent - what do you want to achieve?

You should not use the polymorphic relationship if you simply like to aggregate cakes available in the mall's shops for the mall model. You can use the following relationship to achieve such a design:

```
class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
  has_many :cakes, :through => :stores
end
```

The polymorphic approach is a perfect choice if the two sets (cakes in the mall, cakes in the mall's stores) don't correlate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is exactly my intent, mall cakes and store cakes are similar (hence one model) but separate entities. But as I go deeper into the whole process, I think I shall abandon polymorphism for now and just create another model. Details outlined above.